# Linux can use memory (RAM) which it should not (?) see

Tags: linux, ram, linux-mint

I have a question about GNU/Linux. My laptop has 6GB of RAM, and I have installed Linux Mint 17.2 x86 on it. From my knowledge, 32-bit OSes can handle only 4 GB, but Linux Mint reports that it can use all of 6 GB.

[image: screen of htop]

How is that possible?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "see memory you can't see"? Given this is more about Linux OS than say, programming it or bash, I suggest asking on the Unix/Linux site.

Comment: But +1 for your color scheme.

Comment: @Hunter Stevens thank you for remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Physical Address Extension (PAE), sometimes referred to as Page Address Extension, is a memory management feature for the IA-32 architecture. PAE was first introduced in the Pentium Pro. It defines a page table hierarchy of three levels, with table entries of 64 bits each instead of 32, allowing these CPUs to access a physical address space larger than 4 gigabytes (23^2 bytes).

(c) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

> Physical Address Extension (PAE) is a feature found on almost all 32
>   bit processors produced after Pentium Pro, ie. younger than around
>   1995. Because PAE is close to being a standard it is now a requirement for Ubuntu: During installation the processor is prompted for the PAE
>   flag, and only if present the process will carry on.
>
> Lubuntu and Xubuntu offered a PAE and a non-PAE release up to and
>   including 12.04, but from 12.10 only the PAE releases are maintained.

(c) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE